# how to extract moments of GB from moment generating function?

Tags: finance, quantitative, matlab

I'm searching for the moments of geometric brownian motion using the gmm optimization program. the aim is to make the process y(t) of returns follows a normal distribution Are there any packages in MATLAB that are capable of this?

Answer (score 4):

I found [these nice lecture note](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/FE-Notes/4700-07-Notes-GBM.pdf) by Karl Sigman on the web. On page three you see if $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$ then the moment generating function (mgf) of $X$ is given by 
$$M_X(s) = E(exp(sX)) = \exp( \mu s + \sigma^2 s^2 /2)$$
Thus for Brownian motion with drift $X_t$ you get 
$$
M_{X_t}(s) = E(exp(s X_t)) = \exp( \mu t s + \sigma^2 s^2 t /2).
$$
Finally for $S_t = S_0 \exp(X_t)$, i.e. the geometric Brownian motion you get
$$
E[S_t^n] = S_0^n E[\exp(X_t)^n] =  S_0^n E[\exp(n X_t)] = S_0^n M_{X_t}(n),
$$
which can be calculated by the mgf of $X_t$. Then you get all moments by a simple formula.